# Auto hide all other apps when clicking on an app’s window

Tags: macos, window-manager

Heading says it all really. I have lots of windows open, belonging to lots of apps. Sometimes when working in one app I click on one of the windows of another app, and that window becomes the active window, **but** all of the app’s other windows are still hidden!

Is there a way for me to automatically hide all windows from all apps when I click on the window of one app?

**Here is an example of what I mean:**

- I have five TextEdit windows open in various locations on screen
- I’m currently using Safari and only one of the TextEdit windows is partly visible
- I want to navigate to the TextEdit window from Safari and somehow automatically hide all other apps in one process

BTW, I know I can use the <kbd>OPTION</kbd>+<kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> shortcut once I have made the other app’s window active, but I was hoping there was some way to do this as part of the navigation.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, you can do exactly what you want by holding the <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd> keys down as you click on the window.

Also, if you just want to hide the last app (i.e. not all other apps) you can just hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key while you click on the other window.

Answer (score 3):

You could activate the `Single Application Mode`. Here's what it does:

- you have five TextEdit windows open in various locations on screen
- you're currently using Safari
- you navigate to the TextEdit window that's in the background by **clicking it's icon in the dock**
- all other apps will be hidden automatically

You can activate `Single Application Mode` by opening `/Applications/Terminal`, then simple copy the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock single-app -bool true; killall Dock
```

To reverse this behaviour, simply replace `true` with `false`.